# Ganglia data isn't stored as expected

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, ganglia

I am trying to setup ganglia in order to set up monitoring for spark on our cluster.
So far I have installed gmond&gmetad on my master server, and gmond on one of my slaves.
My problem is that I can only see one node on my ganglia web frontend.

I have checked the /var/lib/ganglia/rrds folder, where the rrd files are being created, and I see that both servers contain folders by the same name - ip-10-0-0-58.ec2.internal.
How can I instruct Ganglia to write its data to different folders, in order to differentiate between the nodes?

If any info is missing, I will gladly supply it.
Thanks for the help,
Yaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was solved by removing the bind value from the udp_recv_channel part of the gmond.conf on the master.